# Why is nginx cache folder significantly larger than the static folder it caches?

Tags: caching, nginx

I am trying to make nginx cache the static data from the glassfish server. It caches all the links that contain the word static inside. And these are the settings for those kinds of urls:

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 5m;
proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_cache_lock on;
```

It seems to work fine, but here is what I noticed. The folder that it is supposed to cache, is about 50 MB, but the cache folder inside nginx itself keeps growing and right now is about 400 MB. Why is that? This is because nginx refreshes the cache every 5 minutes, but does not purge the old keys, or what? The max size is set to 10 GB, so that happens after the cache reaches that size? It will start to purge the old records from the cache?

Comment: Default `proxy_cache_key` contains full uri. So `/file.css?x=1` and `/file.css?x=2` will be cached independently. You should configure `proxy_cache_key` so it would fit your needs.

Comment: Well, our urls don't contain something like that. They do contain a version - for example /file.css?version=4.7.5, which changes only after application upgrade, so that nginx would not return a new version. Also I have checked the log and I see there urls like this: scripts/app.js?version=4.7.5&_=1476449220155. OK, so what is this last thing - a timestamp to find when the cache entry was appended?

Comment: Actually you just wrote that your url *contain* something like that. As I said, configure `proxy_cache_key` appropriately. I guess something like `$host$uri?$arg_version` should be good enough

Comment: No, that's nginx log , the last _=1476449220155 was appended manually by nginx, not by the app.

Comment: Nginx doesn't  append anything. It's appended by something else, probably by jQuery, webpack, etc/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, apparently this was an issue. Som other app appended timestamp while interacting with ours. After making nginx use proxy_cache_key as $host$uri?$arg_version - everything works just fine.